# Why is the following string concatenation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the function:

```
  function countryType() {
    var country = $('#inputCountry').val();
    var visaFreeCountry = _.contains(visaFreeCountries, country);
    var specificCountry = _.contains(specificCountries, country);

    if (visaFreeCountry) {
      return 'Visa-free Country';
    } else if (specificCountry) {
      return 'Specific Country';
    } else {
      return 'Regular Country';
    }
  }
```

And I'm appending like like this:

```
$('#content').html('<div class="alert alert-info">' + countryType + '</div>');
```

For some reason it works when I only do

```
$('#content').html(countryType);
```

But as it is right now it attaches the function instead of the result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need empty parenthesis after the function name if you want to call it - `$('#content').html('<div class="alert alert-info">' + countryType() + '</div>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the function to get the returned string

```
$('#content').html('<div class="alert alert-info">' + countryType() + '</div>');
```

The reason it works when you just add the function as an argument is because html() does something like this

```
$.fn.html = function(value) {
    if (value === undefined) {

        // returns the HTML if no argument passed

    } else if (typeof value === "string" .... ) {

        // if it's a string, treat it like a string, and this is where you fail

    } else if (jQuery.isFunction(value)) {

        // this is what happens when ONLY a function is passed

        this.each(function (i) {
            var self = jQuery(this);

            self.html(value.call(this, i, self.html())); // calls the function
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the function with `()`

```
$('#content').html('<div class="alert alert-info">' + countryType() + '</div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

`countryType` is a function so you have to invoke it with parentheses:

```
$('#content').html('<div class="alert alert-info">' + countryType() + '</div>');
```

The second syntax works because jQuery's [`html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) function can accept a function directly, and invokes it to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

As a few people have already answered, you must invoke your function with paranthesis `countryType()`.

The reason why `$('#content').html(countryType);` works without parenthesis is because the `.html()` function optionally takes a function as a argument according to the [documentaion](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml).